# trigger css transition from a different element

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a `div` which has 2 images inside of it. Both the images are wrapped in a single `a` tag.

The first image is a solid image, it has a relative position. The second image is a transparent PNG that sits over the top of the solid image with absolute positioning. Both images are the same size & both images have a lowered opacity.

Basically I want to be able to transition both images to full opacity on hover, but as the transparent PNG covers the solid image completely. Using `:hover` only triggers the transition for the top image, because I'm technically not hovering over the solid image below.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:hover` pseudo class of the parent `a` element instead:

```
div a:hover img {opacity:1;}
```

This will apply the transition to both child `img` elements simultaneously.

Comment: Of Course! Silly oversight on my behalf! Many thanks, worked a treat!